# Extract values from xml in php

Tags: php, xml, api

I have xml in the below format after getting it from the api call using simplexml_load_string php function

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Code] => 0 [Description] => Success )
[XMLVersion] => 8.9.62 )
```

How i will get the value of code & description to use further.

Comment: the manual page has examples: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: i tried in this way 
  $res = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));

$result = get_object_vars($res);
$res_info = get_object_vars($result['UserDetails']);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($res_info); echo "</pre>";
$EmpID = $res_info['@attributes']['EmpID'];
$FName = $res_info['FName'];
$LName = $res_info['LName'];
$Email = $res_info['Email'];
$UserName = $res_info['UserName'];
$TID = $res_info['TID'];

it is working, but not a good way

Comment: [@attributes]  is creating problem, xml is more complex

Comment: If you would post a sample xml file...just a node or two, i think you will get more concise and to the point answers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it looks like you should be able to access the attributes in a number of ways. Assuming the XML

```
<UserDetails Code="0" Description="Success">
    <FName>Bob</FName>
    etc...
```

Starting from here:

```php
$res = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch)); 
$result = get_object_vars($res); 
$res_info = get_object_vars($result['UserDetails']);
```

Then either of the below should work:

```
// Accessing from the UserDetails SimpleXMLElement
echo $result['UserDetails']['Description'];
// Via the subsequent
echo $res_info['@attributes']['Description'];
```

If this doesn't work, maybe you could post the XML part that this comes from, or your code is dumping the Object you posted.